# Issue with closing panel

Tags: asp.net

I got a asp.net page  that hold DGV on the top , and panel with CollapsiblePanelExtender, in this panel I hold textbox, button etc'..when one of my function there (update/delete/insert) is finish, I want that the panel will close automatically.
I got function in javascript:

```
  function hidePanel() {
        $get("<%= Panel1.ClientID%>").style.display = 'none';
        return false;
    }
```

I try to use it with:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Hide", "hidePanel();", true);
```

its close the upper side of the page that hold DGV, instead of closing the panel,
any suggestion why is not working?

Comment: ASP.NET does not have a DGV control.  That's WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

When you update your page in the server-side code call

```
 Panel1.ClientState = True
```

This will extend the panel on postback and

```
Panel1.ClientState = False
```

should hide the panel.